# How can I align an item to the center while ignoring other items in the row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

So I tried creating multiple buttons which are centered on the screen and have line breaks between them. I wanted them to make up a column together. This wouldn't have been much of a problem, however each of the buttons has an inline div in its row containing text, which is controlled by a js script. When I try centering the button, It automatically treats the button and the text/div as a whole, and centers both of them together. I don't need the text divs to lign up vertically, but I want the buttons to.

I have tried different alignments on the text, but it won't change anything. I also tried using tables as a last hacky resort, which kind of worked out, but wasn't viable as a solution because it requires a lot of hacky boilerplate html and also I just don't want to use tables in general.

Comment: *"each of the button has an inline DIV"* - first of `DIV` is not a valid descendant, child of `BUTTON`. Oh, in its ROW...  OK I'm getting lost. Please [edit] to create a [mcve]. Read [ask]. I also believe that an image sketch of the desired output would be necessary for your specific case for us to understand.

Comment: Yea I was thinking of adding that. I kinda just whipped up this question hoping that there was a straightforward answer that I just missed.